# Selenium 2 WebDriver implementation not handling expandable menus correctly

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page where clicking on a button (say EXPAND_CONTEXT_MENU, implemented internally as an href) causes a hidden context menu to expand under it, after which I click on of the menu items in the context menu.

Since Selenium 2 does not allow direct access to hidden elements, I first click on EXPAND_CONTEXT_MENU and then click the desired menu item.

While attempting to test this solution, InternetExplorerDriver displays a peculiar behavior. The first click on EXPAND_CONTEXT_MENU expands the menu alright, but before the second click (for selecting the menu item) can occur, EXPAND_CONTEXT_MENU gets minimized again. This results in an ElementNotVisibleException when the second click occurs.

FirefoxDriver performs this test fine. I am using IE8 and Firefox for testing.

Note - in the actual AUT, just a hover on EXPAND_CONTEXT_MENU expands the context menu.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm experience a similar problem with a hoverover menu. Hovering over the root item brings up the options list but it will disappear on me before I can select a child. I'm testing in IE

Answer (score 0):

use the mouse functionality to hover the mouse over the relevant element:

```
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//foo")); 
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```

You will need to import locatable, it's not pulled in by default:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I'm using python bindings, and the python equivalent is to use the ActionChain class to move the mouse. On IE, using this to move the mouse has no effect. The menu still appears and then disappears as if the mouse wasn't over it.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an event binding that is not firing correctly. Try firing different events via jquery (assumes that **driver** is the WebDriver instance and that **element** is the element you want to fire the event on):

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(string.Format("$(arguments[0]).trigger('click');", element);
```

Comment: I don't think that's a solution. The problem isn't the click, the problem is that the menu which appears after the click only appears for a brief amount of time before disappearing. By the time the second click happens, the item is invisible and webdriver thus refuses to click on it.

Comment: You have to understand how javascript events work; this is not uncommon behavior when an event is fired in an unexpected way (like the way WebDriver might do it). I often see elements appear and immediately disappear because a couple of events conflicted, or the bindings were not set up correctly in the webpage.
Before you completely discard my suggestion, it might be worth your time to actually try it if you haven't already done so.