# Context click in Selenium 2.2

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Got problem with opening custom context menu using advanced user interactions API in Selenium 2 (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions).

Here is C# code:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.flickr.com/photos/davidcampbellphotography/4581594452/");
IWebElement photoDiv = driver.FindElement(By.Id("photo"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
var context = actions.ContextClick(photoDiv).Build();
context.Perform();
```

Still this code doesn't open context menu but simply clicks on the image.

Still many other interactions work fine, like those at [this blogpost](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2011/selenium-advanced-user-interactions.html).

I'm using Firefox 5 on Windows XP, Selenium version 2.2.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions how to make it work.

UPDATE:
However, the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482012/selenium-2-webdriver-implementation-not-handling-expandable-menus-correctly/6123168#6123168) does the same (left click instead of context click).

```
ILocatable loc = (ILocatable)photoDiv;
IMouse mouse = ((IHasInputDevices)driver).Mouse;
mouse.ContextClick(loc.Coordinates);
mouse.MouseMove(loc.Coordinates, 15, 15);
```

Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be [that bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1722).
It is stated in the user group [here](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/606126c7fc4ecce/e4b67af1dcab5ef0?lnk=gst&q=context#e4b67af1dcab5ef0), though the bug is about double click.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a robot click, Although they're not the most efficient way of doing so, but as long as the browser window is the top window it'll click the co-ordinates you set

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(650, 590);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Maybe this will help you :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'll install Selenium and check it out, and re-test the code as well to see if the bug still exists. Will report back in a couple of days :)